# I cannot enter the letter C in the form

Tags: forms

I have installed three different form plugins and they all have the same problem, I can't type the letter C in the form, if I press the C key it doesn't show in the form.

link: https://rauden.ro/contact/

Comment: Some of your JS is blocking it, so it is most likely another plugin/feature. Might be a failed attempt to block copying text?

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was a plugin that block copying text, I appreciate!

Comment: @RăuțuDenis can you post that as an answer? The site still thinks you need an answer

Comment: @TomJNowell how can I make it?

Comment: There's a larger box underneath this with the title "Your Answer" and formatting controls, and a post your answer button. These are just comments on your original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have some functionality to block the `C` character. If you disable JavaScript and disable the loading indicator, you can use the character.

There is a lot of discussion online on the merit of these kinds of tools (trying to stop copying). As you've seen now: it worsens other functionality while giving little benefit (I can still copy with JS disabled, e.g.)